# Hooks to trigger a callback when adding, removing, rearranging or updating a widget in the widget area

Tags: hooks, actions

I am looking for hooks that fire when inside of Appearance -> Widgets:

- A widget gets added to a widget area
- A widget gets deleted from a widget area
- Widgets are being rearranged to new positions
- A widget is being saved

I am looking to trigger a callback function after any of these events occur. My callback function simply triggers the purge cache function of the caching plugins I am using.

So far I have only found a hook called `delete_widget`, which gets triggered when a widget is being deleted.

`add_action( "delete_widget", "my_function_purge_cache" , 10, 3);` This works as intended.

However I can't find hooks for the other 3 events.

Reading through [class-wp-widget.php](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php#L599-L602) I can see widgets use `update_option` to save any changes made to the widgets, including adding, removing, reordering and saving a widget.

`update_option` does have a hook called `updated_option` which fires after a setting has been successfully updated. I tested this hook using:

`add_action( 'updated_option', 'my_function_purge_cache', 10, 3 );` and it seems to work as expected. My function is being called on all 4 events that I was looking for. However this might be an overkill as this gets triggered whenever any option is updated across WordPress and I have no idea how often this occurs. Worst case some 3rd party plugin calls `update_option` during each page visit.

Comment: Just check the option name inside the updated_option callback and only purge if it’s updating widgets.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `updated_option` hook and checking if a widget or sidebar has been updated.

When a widget is added, removed or saved, the `update_option` hook is fired.

All widget option names start with "`widget_`". By checking if the option name starts with "`widget_`" we can determine if a widget was added, removed or saved.

When widgets are being reordered within a widget area, the new positions are being saved to the option `sidebars_widgets`.

The hook `updated_option` fires immediately after an option has been successfully updated. Note: `updated_option` will not fire if the old value and the new value are the same.

```
function purge_cache_on_widget_change( $option, $old_value, $value ) {
    if( substr( $option, 0, 7 ) === 'widget_' || $option === 'sidebars_widgets' ) {
        my_function_purge_cache();
    }
}
add_action('updated_option','purge_cache_on_widget_change', 10, 3);
```